# Cython crashes Python kernel when running code that passes struct of pointers to c function

Tags: python, cython

Getting memory allocation errors when running a compiled version of the following code.  This is an application where a struct of pointers is defined and I would like to assign a value to the pointer and then pass this struct to c code.  I have seen other examples and questions on this subject and I believe this is being done correctly, however still having issues.

The code will compile fine, however it crashes Python when running it. Debugging with Visual Studio, it is showing a memory access violation. I have researched this quite a bit but am unable to come up with a reason why this is happening.  Was able to reproduce this on a different computer.

I believe it has something to do with how the struct `test_M` is being allocated and referenced on the stack.  I've tried several different variations of defining the test_M.param.gain_val, the one shown does allow the code to compile fine and I can get the output to print on the screen. However, Python crashes immediately after this.

Unfortunately I can not modify the c code because this is the format auto-generated code from Matlab/Simulink embedded coder.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Using:
python = 3.6
cython = 0.26
numpy = 1.13.1
Visual Studio 2017 v15
```

ccodetest.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct P_T_ P_T;
typedef struct tag_T RT_MODEL_T;

struct P_T_ {
double gain_val;
};

struct tag_T {
  P_T *param;
};

void compute(double array_in[4], RT_MODEL_T *const test_M)
{
    P_T *test_P = ((P_T *) test_M->param);

    int size;
    size = sizeof(array_in);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
    array_in[i] = array_in[i] * test_P->gain_val;
    }

}
```

cython_param_test.pyx

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Free
np.import_array()

cdef extern from "ccodetest.c":
    ctypedef tag_T RT_MODEL_T
    ctypedef P_T_ P_T
    cdef struct P_T_:
        double gain_val
    cdef struct tag_T:
        P_T *param
    void compute(double array_in[4], RT_MODEL_T *const test_M)

cdef double array_in[4]

def run(
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, mode='c'] x_in,
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2, mode='c'] x_out,
        np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=1, mode='c'] gain):

    cdef RT_MODEL_T* test_M = <RT_MODEL_T*> PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(RT_MODEL_T))

    global array_in

    test_M.param.gain_val = <double>gain
    cdef int idx

    try:

        for idx in range(len(x_in)):
            array_in[idx] = x_in[idx]

        compute(array_in, test_M)

        for idx in range(len(x_in)):
            x_out[idx] = array_in[idx]

    finally:
        PyMem_Free(test_M)

    return None
```

setup.py

```
import numpy
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

def configuration(parent_package='', top_path=None):
    from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration
    config = Configuration('', parent_package, top_path)
    config.add_extension('cython_param_test',
                         sources=['cython_param_test.pyx'],
                         # libraries=['m'],
                         depends=['ccodetest.c'],
                         include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
    return config


if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = configuration(top_path='').todict()
    params['cmdclass'] = dict(build_ext=build_ext)
    setup(**params)
```

run_cython_param_test.py

```
import cython_param_test
import numpy as np

n_samples = 4
x_in = np.arange(n_samples, dtype='double') % 4
x_out = np.empty((n_samples, 1))
gain = np.ones(1, dtype='double') * 5

cython_param_test.run(x_in, x_out, gain)

print(x_out)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cdef RT_MODEL_T* test_M = <RT_MODEL_T*> PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(RT_MODEL_T))
```

You allocate space for a `RT_MODEL_T`. `test_M` has one member, a pointer to a `P_T`. Allocating space for the `RT_MODEL_T` only allocates space to store the pointer - it doesn't allocate a `P_T` to be pointed to. Where `param` points is completely arbitrary at the moment and is most likely a memory address that you aren't allowed to write to.

```
test_M.param.gain_val = ...
```

You attempt to write to an element of the `P_T` pointed to by `param`. However, `param` does not point to an allocated `P_T`.

```
... = <double>gain
```

You attempt to cast a numpy array to a double. This does not make sense at all. You probably want to get the first element of the numpy array or you should pass `gain` as just a double rather than a numpy array of doubles?

---

Since `test_M` and its contents don't need to live beyond the end of the function they're allocated in, I'd be tempted to allocate them on the stack instead, and that way you can completely avoid `malloc` and `free`:

```
cdef RT_MODEL_T test_M # not a pointer
cdef P_T p_t_instance

p_t_instance.gain_val = gain # or gain[0]?

test_M.param = &p_t_instance

# ...
compute(array_in, &test_M) # pass the address of `test_M`
```

Only do this if you are sure of the required lifetime of `test_M` and the `P_T` it holds a pointer to.